# Accessing a List object stored as a session variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, oop

I have a list of id's stored in my ASP.NET application's session.  For contextual purposes:

- This is a facebook-like chat module.  Id's are relevant to individual chat tabs.
- jQuery is handling many things and requires the specific id of each box.
- When a new chat session is created, it is given an id on the serverside used for client-side interaction like jQuery event binding

The program works fine I just need a way to access the list on the front-end.  I would assume converting the object to a json object makes the most sense but I'm not quite sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always render server-side content to the client by doing something like:

```
var ids = '<%= Session["Keys"].ToString() %>';
```

And then split the results and convert them however you want them.  It really depends on what the ID's look like (just numbers, or is more info involved), and how you use them, so it's hard to provide additional advice without more information about the structures.

Comment: Yea so this has been my dilemma.  I took a look at json serialization but it seems a bit of overkill.  I have a list of numbers, nothing more.  I was looking for something closer to a snippet like yours above to spit out the list as a string and parse it client-side, but not too confident with the use of cs code on .aspx pages

Comment: you can convert the list to the string on the server easily as:  `String.Join(",", (List<string>)Session["Keys"])`, and then split the results by comma in client-side javascript.

Comment: new issue:  I've used your method above and serverside it works fine, thanks for the suggestion.  however, now I store the string in a protected property and call it via <%= varName %> but the string is truncated at the first comma (which does not show).  any idea why this is happening?

Comment: interestingly enough, using a period as the delimiter works just fine.  I wonder whats going on here ^_^...thanks for the help I can work from here but would still like to figure out whats up with the comma not being passed properly if you have any thoughts

Comment: No idea, comma works for me, unless your content inside the keys collection already has a comma or something like that....

Comment: scratch that all...I didnt represent of the output as a string in JS so it was returning the literal 1,38 rather than "1,38" and breaking the code...duhh.  thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your project http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json then review this resource http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm to work out how to do the serialize/deserialize operations ;o)